# Reducible binary quadratic form

Tags: binary-quadratic-forms, discriminant

Let $f(x,y)=(ex+fy)(gx+hy); \ x,y,e,f,g,h \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a reducible integral binary quadratic form. Is there a criterion to determine if a number is represented by this form? In particular, does such a criterion exist for if an integral binary quadratic form has square discriminant?

Comment: Prime factorization, or Gauss's Disquisitiones.